# Google Calendar API javascript Error:Origin Mismatch

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a simple javascript code I found here: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-new-js-library-to-unlock-power-of.html

It basically acquires authentication to a google Calendar and retrieves the list of events contained in it. I have registered my web application and obtained a client ID and API Key.

I'm facing this error: "Error: Origin mismatch", I'm running the javascript locally using localhost and I set my homepage in the google application registration to localhost as well.

any help would be immensely appreciated.

the code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='content'>
      <h1>Events</h1>
      <ul id='events'></ul>
    </div>
    <a href='#' id='authorize-button' onclick='handleAuthClick();'>Login</a>

    <script>
    var clientId = '506979856128.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var apiKey = 'AIzaSyAGbQAZQU0YNL8hK5EU69exIg7_sOg3JoA';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

      function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
  checkAuth();
}

function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true},
      handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  if (authResult) {
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    makeApiCall();
  } else {
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
    authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
   }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth.authorize(
      {client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false},
      handleAuthResult);
  return false;
}

function makeApiCall() {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'primary'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.items[i].summary));
        document.getElementById('events').appendChild(li);
      }
    });
 });
}
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad">                 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error origin mismatch today.after bit of search i got the reason.

While creating the Google Api Access,we have to specify ***Authorized Redirect URIs*** and ***Authorized Redirect URIs***.

Now if you call the Login from URIs other than specified in ***Authorized Redirect URIs***, `error:Unknown Origin is thrown`

**FYI**:I have seen that you are running the javascript locally using localhost.
       It means that You have not added localhost uri to Authorized Redirect URIs.

But Don't waste your time doing that.Authorized Redirect URIs will not accept localhost uri.It's due to Chrome's same origin policy.and If you  run chrome with the disable-web-security flag, it'll work locally too.

Comment: Sounds reasonable but...

```cd "/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/"``` --> ```./Google\ Chrome\ Canary --disable-web-security``` --> ```Trace/BPT trap: 5``` --> ```Google Chrome quit unexpectedly.```

Comment: @CraigMorgan: chrome extension in FF??

Comment: Nope - just plain old FF

Answer (score 1):

The problem of origin mismatch can be solved by taking care for **Redirect URIs** and **Javascript Origins** when creating **Client ID** in **Google Developers Console**.

The **Javascript Origins** should **not** end with `/`.

*Example*:  `http://example.com/` --> The correct format will be `http://example.com`.